# Limitations of curl and wget

Tags: curl, wget

I am wondering why certain URLs load without a hassle in a browser tab but timeout with tools like `wget` and `curl`.
Here is an example URL:
https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines

I have tried creating download scripts for this webpage using `curl` and `wget` but without success (i.e. they all hang up).

```
wget --adjust-extension -t 2 -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines" -O gme.html

wget --adjust-extension -t 2 -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' "www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines" -O gme.html

curl -o 01.html https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines

curl -o 01.html www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines
```

Comment: This is totally offtopic, but the right strategy is to open the network tools pane in your browser (e.g. with `Ctrl-Shift-E` in firefox) and from there right click on the request then `Copy` => `Copy As cURL` which will give you a `curl` command line which you could then adjust. In your case, you could see that that site works without a `Cookie` header, but NOT without the right `Referer` and `User-Agent`. It would also need keep-alive and only send compressed data.

Comment: @user414777 If this is off topic, I'd expect to see a close vote from you.

Answer (score 0):

Their web server may well look at the `User-Agent:` header in the request and refuse to server requests coming from `curl` or `wget` and similar tools.  They may choose to do this because they might not want scripted access to their web content. In fact, part of their [terms of service](https://www.nasdaq.com/legal) (which you agree to by merely accessing their site) says

> Use of the Services. To use our Services you must:
>
> [...]
>
> Not use any automated process to access or use the Service or any process, whether automated or manual, to capture data or content from the Service or circumvent any mechanisms for preventing the unauthorized reproduction or distribution of the Service for any reason;

Changing the `User-Agent:` header used in the request is a matter of finding the correct options in the manual of your tool, deciding whether using that option would be legal or not in your use case, and acting on that consideration.

Comment: The web server looks at each and every header (not just the `User-Agent`) and this is not the right place for legal advice.